# Vue lifecycle hook race condition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, lifecycle-hook

I have a question regarding the Vue lifecycle hooks.  I have some method that I want to call first in a hook, but another method is calling before.

The desired method is `loadData()` that calls from `beforeMount`. This method is responsible for API requests. But, it calls after the method `getIndex`.

The  method that calls first is `getIndex` and I want it to call last:

*myFile.vue*

```html
<b-form>                
   <app-select
      labelName="Name"
      fieldType="Type"
      :val="getIndex('M','Q',null,null)">
   </app-select>
</b-form>
```

I tried to call `loadData()` from `mounted()`, `beforeMounted()` but each time it is the second one. Does anyone know the answer? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to deal with this is by using `v-if` to delay the rendering of the `<app-select>` until the data is ready:

```html
<app-select v-if="loadedData" ...
```

Where `loadedData` is `this.loadedData` or whatever data property will be populated when the hook finishes loading.  The `<app-select>` won't begin to render until the data is ready.   This is essentially similar to the concept of a watch, but in the template.

Comment: Thanks . Will try

Comment: If I use getIndex() everywhere, how can I postpone the render?

Comment: Wrap everything in a `<div v-if="loadedData">`.  Or load the data in the parent of this component and put the `v-if` there, passing the data as a prop:  `<thischild v-if="loadedData" :data="loadedData">`